# Continue processing bat file after opening executable

Tags: batch-file, photoshop

I am calling a .jsx script via .bat script (the .bat is a necessary startup script for my users). The .jsx is launching Photoshop with specific color settings. After the .jsx runs the .bat does not continue.

I can quit Photoshop manually and the .bat will continue. Any one have any ideas how to allow the .bat to carry on after calling the .jsx?

.bat script:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe" "path\PS_Color_Settings.jsx"
```

.jsx script:

```
setColorSettings();  

function setColorSettings() {  
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();  
    var ref = new ActionReference();  
    ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" ), stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" ) );  
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID( "capp" ), charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ) );  
    desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), ref );  


    var colorSettingsDesc = new ActionDescriptor();  
    colorSettingsDesc.putString( stringIDToTypeID( "workingRGB" ), """sRGB IEC61966-2.1""" );  
    colorSettingsDesc.putEnumerated(  stringIDToTypeID( "policyRGB" ), stringIDToTypeID( "policy" ), charIDToTypeID( "Cnvr" ) );  
    colorSettingsDesc.putBoolean( stringIDToTypeID( "askMismatchOpening" ), true );  
    colorSettingsDesc.putBoolean( stringIDToTypeID( "askMismatchPasting" ), true );  
    colorSettingsDesc.putBoolean( stringIDToTypeID( "askMissing" ), true );  
    desc.putObject( charIDToTypeID( "T   " ), stringIDToTypeID( "colorSettings" ), colorSettingsDesc );  
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "setd" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );  
}
```

After the .jsx runs and photoshop launches, the .bat script ceases and does not move on to the next steps. I have tried inserting a 'GOTO' and an 'END' after calling the .jsx but nothing seems to get the .bat script back on track. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `START` command to launch the program. `start "" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe" "path\PS_Color_Settings.jsx"`

Comment: I don't think this is a Java question.  If you put different tags on it, you're more likely to get an answer from someone familiar with JSX.

Comment: Note that the JSX is not running Photoshop. Instead, a JSX file is provided to Photoshop (as would be an XML or .properties file) which uses it as it wants (which is likely to execute it in a javascript environment to configure itself). In conclusion the problem is straightforward : you would like the execution of an executable not to block the execution of the .bat script it's launched from (question that @Squashman answers above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`START`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command (as @Squashman suggested):

`START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`

So something like this (expanded for readability)

```
 @echo off
 set "pspath=C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe"
 set "jsxpath=path\PS_Color_Settings.jsx"
 set "title=not required"

 start "%title%" "%pspath%" "%jsxpath%"
 echo Opened Photoshop, still running...
 pause
```